# How to find out next date if i have already knows day of this date?

Tags: php, date, datetime, datepicker, mktime

Suppose ,i have three variables .

```
$curr_day = "monday";
$curr_date = "12/12/2222";//('d/m/y')
$next_day = "friday";

$next_date = ??;
```

what will be the next date ?
Is there any **"php functions"** that helps me to find out $next_date ?

Thanks In Advance .

Comment: Is this Friday is in same week ?

Comment: Friday will be grater than current date ...... that's sure .
Just remind you here i am looking for functions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need:

```
var_dump(new DateTime('2016-05-29 next friday'));
```

will give you next friday after "2016-05-29".

```
object(DateTime)[2]
  public 'date' => string '2016-06-03 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
```

You complete example with the function you need:

```
$curr_day = "monday";
$curr_date = "26/05/2016";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $curr_date);
$nextDate = new DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d').' next friday');
var_dump($nextDate->format("d/m/Y"));

string '27/05/2016' (length=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try :

```
var_dump(new DateTime('next friday'));
```

Comment: Current date means not "today ". It might be future date . In that case ?

Comment: see answers below they explain how to get the result from a given date, i just gave you the way yo go.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `DateTime` to solve date related problems. Take a look at the following example:

```
// Make a new DateTime object using your date
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-05-25');

// Modify the object to get the next date
$date->modify('next friday');

// Output the date
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `$curr_date` is in `m/d/Y` format *(if it's not, please clarify your question because 12/12 it's confusing)*.

You could use `strtotime` as an easy way to calculate relative dates. See [Example #1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
$curr_day = "Monday";
$curr_date = "12/12/2222";
$next_day = "Friday";

// Convert your string $curr_date to timestamp
$curr_date = strtotime( $curr_date );

// Then use again strtotime to calculate the relative date.
echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime( "next " . $next_day, strtotime( $curr_date ) ) );
```

Hope this helps!

PS: Btw, 12/12/2222 is not Monday but [Thursday](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2222&country=1).

Answer (score 0):

TRY! this...

```
// get next date
$d = new DateTime($curr_date);
$next_date = new DateTime($d->format('d/m/y'));
echo $next_date->modify('+1 day'); //13/12/2222
```